# Block regular users from changing their passwords: only root should be able to

Tags: ssh, security, password

For security reasons, I want to make it so that only root can change user's passwords
This can be achieved if I set `/usr/bin/passwd` to `700`. Now, if password aging is enabled or first login is enabled, when a user logs in with successful or expired password, he is requested to chose a new password. I want to disable this behavior.

OUTPUT:

```
login as: test
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password change requested. Choose a new password.
Enter current password:
```

Expected Output:

```
login as: test
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Your password has expired. Please contact root to change your password.
```

I want a workaround to achieve this. I have done a little research, but I am not sure what entry needs to be added to the pam module. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: That sounds rather like decreasing security rather than improving.

Comment: AU cross-post: [i want only the root to change passwords for all the other users and local users are nor given permission to create his password by any means](http://askubuntu.com/q/746971)

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently no pam module to do this.  Most of pam's functionality consists of *removing* functionality rather than *adding* it.

You can change the password attributes for users so that their password will not expire (for a long time), and expire those manually as needed.

Further reading:

- [prevent users from changing their password ?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/prevent-users-from-changing-their-password-820366/)
- [Prevent linux user from changing their password in ssh](https://superuser.com/questions/547156/prevent-linux-user-from-changing-their-password-in-ssh)